# Swap two nodes in a doubly linked list

Tags: python, linked-list, nodes, doubly-linked-list

I have the following code for trying to swap 2 nodes in a dll:

```
def swap_nodes(self, index_1, index_2):
        node_1 = self[index_1]
        node_2 = self[index_2]

        node_2.next.prev = node_1
        node_2.prev.next = node_1
        node_1.prev.next = node_2
        node_1.next.prev = node_2

        temp_node_1 = node_1
        node_1.next = node_2.next
        node_1.prev = node_2.prev
        node_2.next = temp_node_1.next
        node_2.prev = temp_node_1.prev

def __getitem__(self, index):
        c = 0
        for node in self:
            if c == index:
                return node
            c += 1
        if c < index + 1:
            raise IndexError
```

Running it on this dll:

```
1 <-> 3 <-> 4 <-> 6 <-> 7 <-> 10
```

Produces this one:

```
1 <-> 3 <-> 7 <-> 10
```

How can I make this work?(assume it doesn't include the head/last node)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem you have here is that you're not copying `temp_node_1` and so the next two lines actually *also* modify `temp_node_1`, so that when you try to use the "old version" of the node it actually uses the updated `node_2`.

Try saving the fields of the old version separately instead, so:

```
# Instead of this
temp_node_1 = node_1
# Do this
temp_next = node_1.next
temp_prev = node_1.prev
# And then use these pointers accordingly:
node_1.next = node_2.next               # No change
node_1.prev = node_2.prev               # No change
node_2.next = temp_next
node_2.prev = temp_prev
```

Comment: Didn't know this could also happen with custom objects. Works now, thanks!